# Include headerfiles in the mainwindow.cpp (Qt5) using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, mingw32

First: I'm a total newbie in using cmake especially with Qt5. So my explanations might sound a little weird to you, but I'll try my best.

At the moment I'm about to set up my project using cmake, Qt5 and mingw.

My project structure is the following:

```
Cmake (my project name)
├── headers
│   ├── Controller
│   │   └── Controller.h
│   └── IUI
│       └── mainwindow.h
└── source
    ├── Controller
    │   └── Controller.cpp
    │   └── cmakelists.txt
    └── IUI
        ├── main.cpp
        ├── mainwindow.cpp
        └── mainwindow.ui
        └── cmakelists.txt
```

This is  the cmakelists.txt located in source/IUI

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(CellAnalyser)

find_package (Qt5Widgets)

set (CellAnalyserLib_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/IUI/mainwindow.cpp)
set (CellAnalyserLib_hdr ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/header/IUI/mainwindow.h)
set (CellAnalyserLib_ui  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/IUI/mainwindow.ui)
set (CellAnalyserBin_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/IUI/main.cpp)

set (Source ${CellAnalyserLib_src} ${CellAnalyserBin_src})

qt5_wrap_cpp(CellAnalyserLib_hdr_moc ${CellAnalyserLib_hdr})
qt5_wrap_ui (CellAnalyserLib_ui_moc  ${CellAnalyserLib_ui})

include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

add_library (CellAnalyserLib SHARED 
 ${CellAnalyserLib_src}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_hdr_moc}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_ui_moc}
)

add_executable(CellAnalyser ${Source}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_hdr}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_src}
 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/header/Controller/Controller.h
 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/Controller/Controller.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (CellAnalyserLib Qt5::Widgets)

target_link_libraries (CellAnalyser ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(CellAnalyser ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries (CellAnalyser CellAnalyserLib)
```

So thats been the important part you need to know. Now the question is: why am I not able to include the Header "controller.h" in mainwindow.cpp? The include in main.cpp works fine and I am able to instantiate the controller-class and call functions. But if I try the same exact thing in mainwindow.cpp I get the following as output:

```
CMakeFiles\CellAnalyserLib.dir/objects.a(mainwindow.cpp.obj):mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6itksys18SystemToolsManagerD1Ev'
CMakeFiles\CellAnalyserLib.dir/objects.a(mainwindow.cpp.obj):mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x859): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6itksys18SystemToolsManagerC1Ev'
CMakeFiles\CellAnalyserLib.dir/objects.a(mainwindow.cpp.obj):mainwindow.cpp:(.data+0xfffff740): undefined reference to `itk::NiftiImageIOFactoryRegister__Private()'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-4~1.2-P/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\CellAnalyserLib.dir/objects.a(mainwindow.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
source\IUI\CMakeFiles\CellAnalyserLib.dir\build.make:134: recipe for target 'source/IUI/libCellAnalyserLib.dll' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [source/IUI/libCellAnalyserLib.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:263: recipe for target 'source/IUI/CMakeFiles/CellAnalyserL
ib.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [source/IUI/CMakeFiles/CellAnalyserLib.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, including `controller.h` appears to work fine, if the error messages you provided were complete. Only the linking fails, when CellAnalyserLib is being linked.

The reason for this is that you are using functions obtained from `controller.cpp`, but you are not including `controller.cpp` in any way in your linkage (neither directly as source, nor indirectly through another library). In addition, you are not linking ITK with your CellAnalyserLib.

A possible fix would be to ditch the shared library altogether (replace your `add_*` and `target_link_libraries` statements):

```
add_executable(CellAnalyser ${Source}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_hdr}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_src}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_hdr_moc}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_ui_moc}
 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/header/Controller/Controller.h
 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/Controller/Controller.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (CellAnalyser Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries (CellAnalyser ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(CellAnalyser ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

If ditching the shared library is not an option, you need to clean up your linkage, by not having the same source in two different objects (again, replace your `add_*` and `target_link_libraries` statements):

```
add_library (CellAnalyserLib SHARED 
 ${CellAnalyserLib_src}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_hdr_moc}
 ${CellAnalyserLib_ui_moc}
 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/Controller/Controller.cpp
)

add_executable(CellAnalyser ${CellAnalyserBin_src}
)

target_link_libraries (CellAnalyserLib ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(CellAnalyserLib ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries (CellAnalyserLib Qt5::Widgets)

target_link_libraries (CellAnalyser CellAnalyserLib)
```

Adding headers to `add_*` is not neccessary.

Comment: Thanks Jonas! Your first guess worked right away. I just thought I needed the shared library to add the qt5 widgets. Thanks again :)